# How to make a two columns table responsive with second column going under first one?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I am creating a website using an online editor. I have a simple table with two columns and one row. On desktop, it looks great but on mobile I have to scroll left and right to see the content.

I would like to make it responsive with the second column going under the first one on small screen.

Here is my code:

```html
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
  <table style="height: 452px; width: 821px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="height: 143.6px;">
        <td style="width: 280px; height: 143.6px;"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sc-support-web/en-US/GIF/OnBoarding_Snap_Map" width="250" height="409" /></td>
        <td style="width: 439px; height: 143.6px;">
          <h3 style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #333333;"><b>It all starts with a test</b></span></h3>
          <br />
          <p style="line-height: 1.6; text-align: left;"><span style="color: #333333; font-size: large;">This is an example. This is an example. Testing and testing again.</span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

So on this example, I would like to have the text part going under the picture on small screen. How can I do that please?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use tables for it. Tables are very inconvenient thing in the terms of responsibility.

Use CSS grid layout for it. In my example, try to resize the screen. When it becomes narrow, columns move one under another. When window is relatively wide, you could see them side-by-side.

https://jsfiddle.net/33fLLdzr/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box sidebar"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sc-support-web/en-US/GIF/OnBoarding_Snap_Map" width="250" height="409" /></div>
    <div class="box sidebar2">
        <h3 style="text-align: left;">It all starts with a test</h3>
        <p style="line-height: 1.6; text-align: left;">This is an example. This is an example. Testing and testing again.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
body {
    margin: 40px;
}

.sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
}

.sidebar2 {
    grid-area: sidebar2;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #444;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "sidebar"
        "sidebar2"
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
        grid-template-areas:
        "sidebar sidebar2"
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks John! You made my day and it works.
But I would like to customize it a little bit more.

I want the text to be verticaly centered with the pictures and to get it closer to the pic as shown on this pics: https://res.cloudinary.com/hrscywv4p/image/upload/c_limit,fl_lossy,h_9000,w_1200,f_auto,q_auto/v1/949589/PrtScr_capture_ypwjve.jpg

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a media query in which you apply `display: block; width: 100%; height: auto;` to `table`, `tr` and `td`. That way you make them all regular block elements where the `td`s will flow below each other.

Set the breakpoint as desired. In my snippet I set it to 600px;

And try to avoid inline styles. If you want to use media queries, they are really in your way...

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
}
table {
  height: 452px;
  width: 821px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
tr {
height: 143.6px;
}
td.x {
  width: 280px;
  height: 143.6px;
}

td.y {
  width: 439px;
  height: 143.6px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table,
  tr,
  td.x,
  td.y {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="x"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sc-support-web/en-US/GIF/OnBoarding_Snap_Map" width="250" height="409" /></td>
        <td class="y">
          <h3 style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #333333;"><b>It all starts with a test</b></span></h3>
          <br />
          <p style="line-height: 1.6; text-align: left;"><span style="color: #333333; font-size: large;">This is an example. This is an example. Testing and testing again.</span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes but I have some troubles understanding what you did. You gave two pieces of code. Both are HTML and should be put under each other? Or one is CSS?

Comment: That's a Stackoverflow "snippet" - if you click on "Run Code Snippet" below it, you'll see the result of both together. On top is the stylesheet (CSS), below it the HTML. To apply this to your own code, you copy the CSS either in your stylesheet, or if you don't have one (not so good...) into a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` section of your html file, and the HTML code in the `body`of your page code. That's pretty basic stuff, BTW...

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
    <body>
       <img class="aligncenter wp-image-4684" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sc-support-web/en-US/GIF/OnBoarding_Snap_Map" width="250" height="409" /> 
     
<a href="http://scotiafishing.com/wp-content/uploads/Best-Of-Scotland-Package.pdf" rel="">This is an example. This is an example. Testing and testing again.</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

would you want something like this?